# python background thread cannot trigger function registered at atexit.register()

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a client and server model. The server periodically sends its healthy condition to client. The client has a background thread to take care of it(main thread is doing something else). Once the client notices the server is in a bad status, it will do some clean up work and then kill itself(kill the client process).

The problem is this:
At the very beginning of the process, it does `atexit.register(specific_cleanup_func)`. Once the client recognizes the server is in a bad status, the **background thread** will do `general_cleanup_func()` and `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)`. I hope the `os.kill()` called by background thread will trigger the registered `specific_cleanup_func` but it is not the case. I also tried to call sys.exit() from the background thread but the process does not exit. I wonder how to trigger the registered function from the background thread while killing the process or how to let the background thread ask main thread to do all those cleanup stuff and `sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

atexit module executes only, when program exits "normally", for example, with sys.exit(1). 
You have to add signal handler to catch "os.kill" signal like this:

```
import sys
from signal import signal, SIGTERM


signal(SIGTERM, lambda signum, stack_frame: sys.exit(1))
atexit.register(specific_cleanup_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

A background task should never try to kill a foreground task - it might be doing something important.  The background task should pass a status of "Restart Needed" and the foreground task should exit when convenient or after prompting the user.  This would be an extension of your current status checking.

In your background thread you can have a status that is periodically fetched from the foreground and the foreground can take action based on the returned status.  You could also supply a callback to the background thread that it calls on there being a problem.

Comment: Could you be more specific? How to let the background thread tell the main thread 'I need you to do something'?

Comment: "The server periodically sends its healthy condition to client" - just have it use the same mechanism to send a please restart - e.g. if the current I am OK is a 1 send -1 instead!

Comment: No matter what the server send to the client, it is the background thread in client side who takes care of it. As you mentioned, it is not a good way to ask a background thread to end a process. Then I want to know how could the background thread tell the main thread 'please do these things and exit the process'?